# Get line number python from opened file

Tags: python, parsing, with-statement

I wrote this little Python 2.7 prototype script to try and read specified lines (in this example lines 3,4,5) from a formatted input file. I am going to be later parsing data from this and operating on the input to construct other files.

from sys import argv

```
def comparator (term, inputlist):
    for i in inputlist:
        if (term==i):
            return True
    print "fail"
    return False

readthese = [3,4,5]

for filename in argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            linenum=#some kind of way to get line number from file
            if comparator(linenum, readthese):
                print(line)
```

I fixed all the errors I had found with the script but currently I don't see anyway to get a line number from file. It's a bit different than pulling the line number from a file object since file is a class not an object if I'm not mistakened. Is there someway I can pull the the line number for my input file?

I think a lot of my confusion probably stems from what I did with my with statement so if someone could also explain what exactly I have done with that line that would be great.

Answer (score 8):

You could just [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the file object since `enumerate` works with anything iterable...

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(file):
    if comparator(line_number, line):
        print line
```

Note, this indexes starting at 0 -- If you want the first line to be 1, just tell `enumerate` that's where you want to start:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(file, 1):
    ...
```

<sup>Note, I'd recommend not using the name `file` -- On python2.x, `file` is a type so you're effectively shadowing a builtin (albeit a rarely used one...).</sup>

Comment: originally I had seen this "with open" statement on a different SO answer and I wasn't sure if he had chosen to use file on purpose since it was a type. That was really my main point of confusion, and learning enumerate was helpful. Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: Ahh -- I assume the other answer didn't have a context manager like you do?  When you do `x = open(...)` you get the exact same `x` that you would when you use a context manager:  `with open(...) as x:`.  The difference is that with the latter, the context manager does the additional work of *closing* `x` when the context is exited.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the list structure's index itself like so:

```
with open('a_file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
readthese = [3,4,5]
for lineno in readthese:
    print(lines[1+lineno])
```

Since the list of `lines` already implicitly contains the line numbers based on index+1

If the file is too large to hold in memory you could also use:

```
readthese = [3,4,5]
f = open('a_file.txt','r')
for lineno in readthese:
    print(f.readline(lineno+1))
f.close()
```